# Неверное чтение int из бинарного файла

Tags: c++, c, файлы, visual-c++, файловый-ввод-вывод

На с++ используя fwrite в бинарный файл записывается несколько целых чисел:

```
void main(){
char path[_MAX_FNAME];
cin >> path;
FILE* file = fopen(path, "w");
if (!file) exit(-20);
for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
    fwrite(&j, sizeof(int), 1, file);
}
fclose(file);

FILE* file2 = fopen(path, "r");
if (!file2) exit(-21);
for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
    int i = 0;
    fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, file2);
    cout << i << '\n';
}
fclose(file2);

}
```

При выводе числа 1-25 выводятся нормально, далее вывод неверен до самого конца.

Предполагаю, что 26 = 1A, а 1А является UTF-символом. Как мне игнорировать подобные символы и считывать их как целое число?

Вывод выглядит так:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
...
```

Код завершается успешно, но вывод после 25 неверный.

Comment: Как минимум вы не проверяете коды ошибок

Comment: а почему записали `fclose` во внутрь цикла?

Comment: А в показанном сейчас виде код вообще не компилируется. Зачем вы придумываете его на ходу? Составьте [mcve], скомпилируйте, проверьте и только после этого добавьте проверенный код в текст вопроса

Comment: @AlexGlebe лишь ошибка при форматировании кода здесь

Comment: переменная `path` не инициализирована. первое число должно быть нулём. Вы что-то обманываете.

Comment: Ладно, я могу "додумать" другие забытые вещи, но тогда в показанном здесь виде код у меня вполне работает и выводит числа от 0 до 99 (правда, я проверял в g++)

Comment: Ну и да, первое число абсолютно точно должно быть нулём, оно не может быть единицей вообще никак, так что где-то всё равно обман

Comment: Да напишите `"wb"` и `"rb"`, и будет вам счастье...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишите не `"w"` и `"r"`, а именно `"wb"` и `"rb"` (бинарный файл), и будет вам счастье...

По умолчанию в VC++ текстовый режим, вот вы и получаете ерунду.

Конкретно — считанное число 26 есть значение Ctrl-Z, каковой есть признаком конца *текстового* файла...

Можете убедиться, *не записывая* 26:

```
if (j!=26) fwrite(&j, sizeof(int), 1, file);
```

и посмотрите, что получится...

**Update**

Поигрался с С++ потоками. Эффект на месте :)

```
int main(){
    const char* path = "test";
    ofstream of(path);
    for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
        of.write((char*)&j, sizeof(int));
    }
    of.close();

    ifstream in(path);
    for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
        int i = 0;
        in.read((char*)&i, sizeof(int));
        cout << i << "   ";
    }
    in.close();

}
```

Добавление `ios::binary`, естественно, все разрулило :)

Comment: Точно ли проблема именно в этом? Я бы понял проблемы с числами 10 или 13, но как это может повлиять на 25 или 26, не в курсе

Comment: @andreymal Дошло. ***Ctrl-Z*** *"Осторожно, двери закрываются"*, в смысле, файл в текстовом режиме закрывается...

Comment: Все символы ниже 32 (пробел) являются управляющими и их запись/чтение из файла в текстовом режиме может привести к неочевидному результату.